# How can I get new (not directly supported by IBM) Python packages to SPSS? Is it possible at all?

Tags: python, module, package, spss

I have wanted to get numpy and wxPython packages into spss. When I searched for the answer, I found informations that confused me little bit. On one side it is written that you can use only packages supported by IBM, for the other side you can find informations that you can use many modules in spss or in some texts directly works with packages which are not part of the basic installation of spss (for e. g. wxPython package is used in the *Programming-and-Data-Management-for-IBM-SPSS-Statistics-24* on the page 140. Their example follows:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import wx
app = wx.PySimpleApp()
dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, "Ok to reformat hard disk?",
                       caption="Important Question",
                       style=wx.YES_NO | wx.NO_DEFAULT | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
ret = dlg.ShowModal()
if ret == wx.ID_YES:
    # put Yes action code here
    print "You said yes"
else:
    # put No action code here
    print "You said No"

dlg.Destroy()
app.Destroy()
END PROGRAM.
```

So I tried directly install package through -pip "way", tried to focus on Custom Dialog Builder or to find some modules with .spe and .spd ending and add them... Everything failed. Maybe there is a way in these attempts but I stopped trying too early.

Please can someone guide me to get on the right path? Or how to undestand that?

Thanks a lot!
Jan

Comment: you can use any module you need; the python installation is in the SPSS folder; you also need to install pip, if you have not done so - it is not included with the Python for SPSS. if your Python installation is not added to PATH, you will need to specify the full path when using pip. And you need writing permission for the SPSS folder ;) Hope this makes sense

Comment: Okay. I did that. Found the folder "Python3" in SPSS instalation and tried to instal pip there. When I type the command "python --version" there. Command line responses me back version of Python (Python 3.4.3).

Comment: ..and ? were you able to install pip ? :)

Comment: Sorry i posted it non completely:

When I try to instal pip by command "python -m ensurepip --default-pip", CD writes me beck:
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\program files\ibm\spss\statistics\24\python3\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pip in c:\program files\ibm\spss\statistics\24\python3\lib\site-packages

Comment: And what did u mean by sentence "And you need writing permission for the SPSS folder"?

Comment: when you try to install modules, what message do you get ? If you are not admin on your computer, you might not be able to install modules

Comment: Yes it can be that, Im not admin. But when I instal for example "SPSSINC_TRANSLATE_OUTPUT.spe" from "https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/app?lang=en#/file/2137d2dc-7d77-4fa0-8fdc-527dc9742603" it works well.

Comment: @horace_vr Thank you a lot for getting me on the right way! Finaly I found the way, but it faild on admin permission, how u wrote. It doesnt matter, it is more important that I know the way now ;).

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this  last week and found it properly documented.

1. Install a "system python". This just means to install Python, through your package manager if you're on Linux, or just download and install it if you're on windows. It has to be the same bit-ness (32 or 64) and the same python major version (2 or 3) as you use in SPSS.
2. Install your modules there.
3. In `<SPSS_HOME>\Python\Lib\site-packages` create a file `sitecustomize.py` with content:

```py
import sys
# Assuming windows and standard python folder here.
sys.path.append(r"C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages")
```

Now you can import these modules and use them from the "SPSS python".

btw., [this is the first result](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/226233/obtaining-numpy-scipy-libraries/) when I do an internet search for "numpy in spss", and it explains the same thing I did, if not as exhaustive.